# What is the alternative solution of file_picker in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, pubspec

I tried to put `file_picker` and `tflite_flutter` in the `pubspec.yaml` but it ended up those two package doesn't compatible to each other, it seems like to be there's a bug inside `tflite_flutter` but i want to seek for a fastest solution, here's the log notes that appear:

```
Because file_picker >=5.0.0 depends on ffi ^2.0.1 and tflite_flutter 0.9.0 depends on ffi ^1.0.0, file_picker >=5.0.0 is incompatible with tflite_flutter 0.9.0.
And because no versions of tflite_flutter match >0.9.0 <0.10.0, file_picker >=5.0.0 is incompatible with tflite_flutter ^0.9.0.
So, because eoffice depends on both tflite_flutter ^0.9.0 and file_picker ^5.2.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because eoffice depends on both tflite_flutter ^0.9.0 and file_picker ^5.2.1, version solving failed.)
```

is there any solution so i could use file picker without removing tflite_flutter?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this (tflite: ^1.1.2) instead of tflite_flutter and this will work fine with you , and the link to this lib's pub dev [here](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite)